# Package not found by package manager (YUM)

Tags: virtualbox, yum, centos-7

I'm installing CentOS as a VM on VirtualBox.

I've some problem with some package I want to install from RPF fusion repositories. I found *VirtualBox-guest-additions-5.2.16-1.el7.x86_64* package references [on this pages](http://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/rpmfusion/free/el/updates/7/x86_64/v/VirtualBox-guest-additions-5.2.16-1.el7.x86_64.html) giving me that it is distributed by `Distribution: RPM Fusion`.

But when I run `sudo yum search VirtualBox-guest-additions` I got a `No matches found`.

My repolist seems to have rpmfusion's repo enabled:

```
[foobar@localhost ~]$ sudo yum repolist 
Modules complémentaires chargés : fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.crazyfrogs.org
 * epel: epel.besthosting.ua
 * extras: centos.crazyfrogs.org
 * rpmfusion-free-updates: fedora.tu-chemnitz.de
 * rpmfusion-nonfree-updates: fedora.tu-chemnitz.de
 * updates: centos.mirror.ate.info
id du dépôt                                          nom du dépôt                                                       statut
base/7/x86_64                                        CentOS-7 - Base                                                     9 911
epel/x86_64                                          Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                     12 656
extras/7/x86_64                                      CentOS-7 - Extras                                                     370
rpmfusion-free-updates/x86_64                        RPM Fusion for EL 7 - Free - Updates                                  230
rpmfusion-nonfree-updates/x86_64                     RPM Fusion for EL 7 - Nonfree - Updates                                57
updates/7/x86_64
```

What can I check to understand why this package is not installabled?

Comment: You need an asterisk at the end of your search command. If not there it will only produce results if there's a package with that exact name (and there isn't).

Answer (score 0):

You could always download the files directly from the repo;

[VirtualBox-guest-additions-5.2.16-1.el7.x86_64.rpm](http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/el/updates/7/x86_64/v/VirtualBox-guest-additions-5.2.16-1.el7.x86_64.rpm)

Or why not use the [official](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) VirtualBox repo?

```
[virtualbox]
name=Fedora $releasever - $basearch - VirtualBox
baseurl=http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/rpm/fedora/$releasever/$basearch
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
repo_gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox.asc
```

That provides `VirtualBox-5.2-5.2.8_121009_el7-1.x86_64.rpm` which appears to be the most recent version for CentOS 7 x64.

Comment: I add the https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/rpm/el/virtualbox.repo repo into my _/etc/yum.repos.d_ folder, but a `yum search VirtualBox` does not show me any guest-additionts package

Comment: @Fractaliste I don't see them either; you can browse the repo files here; http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/rpm/